# Show/Hide divs based on date, Dreamweaver Error?

Tags: javascript, date, html, dreamweaver

I created this code while i was on http://jsfiddle.net, after being satisfied with the working code i brought it over to Dreamweaver. i cant get the code to appear. Here's the code:

HTML

```
    <script src="Java.js"></script>

    <div id="one" style="display:none">
    <p>Displays Items Here Until Selected Date.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="two" style="display:none">
    <p>Selected Date</p>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
    window.setInterval(function()
      {
      var current = new Date();
      var expiry  = new Date("Date Here")
      
      if(current.getTime()>expiry.getTime()){
        $('#one').hide();
        $('#two').show();
      }
```

`}, 0000);

$('#one').show(); 
</pre>`

I dont understand why it would show up in fiddle and not dreamweaver.

Comment: don't call it Java, you look foolish if you do.

Comment: Dreamweaver is a wonderful tool, however for "front end view" I would leave to your browser.  Edit the code in Dreamweaver and check it with a browser EVERY TIME

Comment: Running in Chrome with the Developer Console or Firefox with Firebug is by far the most effective means to debug.

Comment: Also, you can call `setInterval` by itself you don't need the `window.`  Also, just because you set it to run every 0 milliseconds doesn't mean it does (if it did the page would lock up).  Is the change in layout something you want to happen the second the time changes or during the next minute, 30 minutes, hour etc.

Comment: @user2020018: Just to clarify what FlavorScape is trying to say - if no one has explained this to you yet. `Java` and `Javascript` are two entirely different languages. `Java` is used in things like games or mobile phones, etc. (Android is based off of Java.) `JavaSCRIPT` on the other hand is what works with web browsers / HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have show in the main script. You have to wrap it in a document.ready or jQuery $.ready() function.

Otherwise the DOM has not loaded and there's no div to show. jsFiddle automatically wraps your code in on ready I think.

Here's the jQuery doc on .ready() http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Ah yes, and jsFiddle may already be including jQuery--- so you have to do it manually somewhere in the body or header.

```
  <script src="pathtojquery.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

Comment: Actually... Reading your answer and the question, chances are, user isn't including jquery at all.